# Parsing string as properties

Tags: java

I am reading a properties file from database.
I checked `java.util.Properties` and there's no method to parse from a `String` instance. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: What is the format of the properties file?

Comment: A properties file or properties from a DB??

Answer (score 113, accepted):

You're right that `java.util.Properties` doesn't have a method to read from a `String` - but in fact it has more general methods that read from an `InputStream` or `Reader`.

So you can call `load` if you have some way of presenting your `String` as either of these, i.e. a source which effectively iterates over characters one by one.  This feels like it ought to exist, and indeed it does - [java.io.StringReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/StringReader.html).

Putting it together, then, is quite straightforward:

```
public Properties parsePropertiesString(String s) {
    // grr at load() returning void rather than the Properties object
    // so this takes 3 lines instead of "return new Properties().load(...);"
    final Properties p = new Properties();
    p.load(new StringReader(s));
    return p;
}
```

Comment: Thank you andrzej, this just helped me after hours of trying to convert and Amazon S3 props file dynamically using jets3t, awesome and so damn simple.

Comment: I feel that "grr" very strongly. Java core libraries and APIs feel optimized for maximal boilerplate.

Answer (score 4):

These two utility methods could write to and read from `String` via [java.util.Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object:

```
/**
 * Converts a {@link Properties} object to {@link String} and you can
 * also provide a description for the output.
 *
 * @param props an input {@link Properties} to be converted to {@link String}
 * @param desc  an input description for the output
 * @return an output String that could easily parse back to {@link Properties} object
 * @throws IOException If writing encounter a problem or if an I/O error occurs.
 */
private static String convert2String(final Properties props, String desc) throws IOException {
    final StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    String propStr;
    try {
        props.store(sw, desc);
        propStr = sw.toString();
    } finally {
        if (sw != null) {
            sw.close();
        }
    }

    return propStr;
}


/**
 * Converts {@link String} to {@link Properties}
 * @param propsStr an {@link String} input that is saved via convert2String method
 * @return a {@link Properties} object
 * @throws IOException if an error occurred when reading from the {@link StringReader}
 */
private static Properties convert2Properties(final String propsStr) throws IOException {
    final Properties props = new Properties();
    final StringReader sr = new StringReader(propsStr);
    try {
        props.load(sr);
    } finally {
        if (sr != null)
            sr.close();
    }

    return props;
}
```

> I found the above two methods useful when there are plenty of properties
>   and you want to save all of them in a `storage or database`, and you don't want to create a huge `key-value` store table.

Answer (score 2):

I use this code to load properties from a single DB column

```
public Properties buildProperties(String propertiesFromString, String entrySeparator) throws IOException {
    Properties properties = new Properties();
    properties.load(new StringReader(propertiesFromString.replaceAll(entrySeparator, "\n")));
    return properties;
}
```

with a simple test

```
@Test
public void testProperties() throws Exception {
    Properties properties = buildProperties("A=1;B=2;Z=x",";");
    assertEquals("1", properties.getProperty("A"));        
    assertEquals("2", properties.getProperty("B"));        
    assertEquals("3", properties.getProperty("C","3"));        
    assertNull(properties.getProperty("Y"));
    assertEquals("x", properties.getProperty("Z"));  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We had a similar problem, the above did not work for us.

The below, however, did.

```
def content = readFile 'gradle.properties'

Properties properties = new Properties()
InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getBytes());
properties.load(is)

def runtimeString = 'SERVICE_VERSION_MINOR'
echo properties."$runtimeString"
SERVICE_VERSION_MINOR = properties."$runtimeString"
echo SERVICE_VERSION_MINOR
```

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13343062)

Comment: The above very much does answer the question of parsing a string as properties.  

    - We take a file of strings  

    - Parse It  

    - Set Strings in the Properties object equal to groovy objects which can be reused anywhere in the Pipeline