# Jenkins pipeline, Groovy sandbox: Interpret properties file

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline step where I extract the build number from an INI file.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38955697/18651) shows how to do this using a Properties object - but for this to work, I have to disable "Use Groovy Sandbox".

How can I solve this in a "Groovy Sandbox" approved manner?

Edit: I would prefer to use methods that are approved out of the box, rather than modifying a whitelist. So this question is really asking how to solve the problem with methods that are already allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on how the Sandbox is implemented / what the Sandbox allows.
If you are using the https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Script+Security+Plugin, then there is a whitelist and a blacklist of methods you might and might not use. Either add the calls you need to the whitelist by approving them on the according approval page or find a way to solve the task with the methods that are allowed.

Comment: Well, then try to solve it with the default whitelist. SO questions like "write me some code please" are off-topic. Try to write the code yourself and then come back to SO if you have a concrete problem you need help with. If the mentioned plugin is the one you are useing, you can find the whitelist at https://github.com/jenkinsci/script-security-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/scriptsecurity/sandbox/whitelists. Basically spoken, you said this is an INI file, so the `Properties` class will not work anyway. You have the content, so just split it by newline and go on.

Comment: Point taken, and thanks for digging up the default whitelist location.